# Swift UI Creating List Bubble Effect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to recreate the following list effect in SwiftUI,

```swift
List(){
  TaskRowComponent(coreRouter: CoreRouter())
}
 .listRowBackground(ColorScheme().field())
 .cornerRadius(10)
 .padding()
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TaskRowComponent: View{
    @ObservedObject var coreRouter: CoreRouter;

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("This is a row!")
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.green)

        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 80, maxHeight: 80, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

I am trying to piece together how to create this effect where the two rows are stacked on top of each other, I do not want them to be packed how list view currently does it. I tried to add padding but it doesn't seem to work, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you going:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach([1, 2], id: \.self) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .blendMode(.overlay)
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.purple]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                                .cornerRadius(9)

                            HStack {
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Bikram Sinkemana")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                                    Text("Kiran Regmi")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }

                                Text("3:1")
                                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                                VStack {
                                    Text("Bikram Sinkemana")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                                    Text("Sagun Karanjit")
                                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]